# The latest eclipse, oxygen has an empty zip

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded eclipse oxygen from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/2/eclipse-java-oxygen-2-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=1248

and when I try to extract the zipped file, it says

[image]

How do I extract the contents of the folder `eclipse-java-oxygen-2-win32-x86_64.zip`

Comment: I can't reproduce you problem, file extracts for me without problems using WinRar. What is its size on your computer? Maybe you didn't download entire archive? Try to download it again (maybe from different source).

Comment: it says the Size on disk is `189,755,392 bytes`, and the Size is `189,752,755 bytes`

Comment: When I tried it with winRAR, it says "The archive is corrupt", I tried downloading it from 2 different mirrors.

Comment: Hard to tell what could be wrong. Since it works for me maybe problem is related to your location. How about trying to download it via some proxy which uses other countries.

Comment: Did you download it using an FTP tool without setting binary mode for the transfer?  That will corrupt it.  Reliably!

Comment: FTP tool to download a HTTP url (see OP) ?

Comment: Yeah, I gave up, I mean if it's "Hard to tell" for you guys, there's not a chance in hell I'm gonna get it. And I'm in India btw, I tried to download it from the North American servers, the one in Canada. Same error. How do I download it via some proxy? U mean like a vpn?

Comment: Is the ZIP file also corrupted if you download it via `https` instead of `http`?

Comment: Well, you can always try Eclipse Installer instead of archive. Visit http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/ and you will find it at the top. Click "Find out more" to see installation instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I searched around a bit and found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/729701/error-when-trying-to-extract-files-from-a-zip-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and it basically says to open the file (your zip archive) using winRAR. It'll probably show you some sort of error, just ignore it.

Then click on the folder (eclipse in my case), and then go to *Tools -> Repair archive* (alternatively you could just press *Alt+R*)

And that should create a new zip file, and you should be good to go. Just extract that new zip file.

[image]